# certification issue, so i would like trust all application

Tags: android, ssl

There is some domain "xyzexample.com" which has invalid/temporary certificate and i would like to use that certification in my android device so i installed in **SETTINGS -> SECURITY -> INSTALL FROM STORAGE** and now i should access that some domain in my browser or application and the certificate will should work but it is not working ***so how do i trust this particular certificate to access that domain in browser or application to make it trusted certificate for now ?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't made as trusted when self sign in certificates.